# Calculating a 2D sliding window matrix for sliding over a large image

Tags: matlab

Essentially I need to calculate these two matrices below as part of a bigger adaptive filter equation. I think I've been able to calculate m(x,y), since it's just a moving window averaging by using `conv2` with A = my 512x512 image, and B = `ones(3,3)/9` However, the second equation I'm pretty unsure of how to calculate it; I have a vague idea of calculating it with for loops, but I'm unsure of it. f(x,y) is a 512x512 image.

[image]

Comment: Why not also `conv2` it? Just do it over `(f-m).^2`, and note if the dimensions of m is the same as f

Comment: So for the local mean, I did: `mean = conv2(f, ones(3)/9, 'same')` ; for the local variance one, would it then be `localvariance = conv2((f-m).^2, ones(3)/9, 'same') ` ?

Comment: Roughly yes. But note that for the mean, using `same` gives you difference in the bounds regard your definition. Just check results for some pixels as example